# Highlight current week in RichFaces calendar

Tags: jquery, jboss, richfaces

Is there a way to highlight the current or selected week in a RichFaces calendar?

```
<rich:calendar value="#{oc.overtimeDate}" requiredMessage="Date 1 is required."
  id="#{oc.overtimeDateId}" isDayEnabled="isDayEnabled"
  dayStyleClass="getDisabledStyle" datePattern="MM-dd-yyyy"
  required="true" firstWeekDay="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<rich:calendar>` has `@dayClassFunction` (see the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.4.Final/vdldoc/rich/calendar.html))

It can look like this:

```
<h:outputStylesheet>
    .highlightWeek {
        color: red;
        background-color: black;
    }
</h:outputStylesheet>
<h:outputScript>
    var currentWeekNumber = … // determine current week number
    chooseDay = function(day) {
        if (day.weekNumber == currentWeekNumber) return 'highlight';
            return '';
        }
</h:outputScript>
<h:form>
    <rich:calendar dayClassFunction="chooseDay" />
</h:form>
```