# how can i highlight the SELECTED or CURRENT week in RICHFACES calendar

Tags: calendar, richfaces, highlight

can anyone please do help me how can i get the value of atleast the current week of the richfaces calendar? ive been doing dis for almost a month.please do help me ASAP.im using rich:calendar and i want to highlight the current or selected week in the calendar. please do help me.im trying to do some codes in calendarmodeldata in javabeans.thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[RichFaces showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&sample=clientStylingDisablement&skin=blueSky) contains good example of highlighted calendar elements.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152356/highlight-current-week-in-richfaces-calendar) for the same question.